# How can I get an NSString value from a "(void)" method into a "(BOOL)" method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, variables, nsstring

I want to get the value of "city" into "CurrentLocation".

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {
    NSString *city = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressCityKey];
}

- (BOOL)fetchAndParseRSS {        
    NSString *currentLocation; // I want 'city' here.
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are your returning void from your reverseGeocoder message? I would have written this like this:

```
- (NSString*)reverseGeocoder:(Placemark*)myPlacemark
{
    // assuming myPlacemark is holding a reference to the dictionary (so no need to retain)
    NSString *city = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:kABPersonAddressCityKey];
    return city;
}

-(BOOL)fetchAndParseRss
{
    // you need to get myPlacemark from somewhere, presumably from the geocode request?
    Placemark * myPlacemark = [self getPlacemark];

    NSString * CurrentLocation = [self reverseGeocoder:myPlacemark];
}
```

In this code I am assuming Placemark is a class with a addressDictionary NSDictionary defined as a property.

If you really need that message to return a void* then you would cast from a NSString* to void* and then back again.

```
- (void*)reverseGeocoder:(Placemark*)myPlacemark
{
    // assuming myPlacemark is holding a reference to the dictionary (so no need to retain)
    NSString *city = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:kABPersonAddressCityKey];
    return (void*)city;
}
```

Then cast it back to an NSString when you assign it (not sure why you would do this):

```
-(BOOL)fetchAndParseRss
{
    // you need to get myPlacemark from somewhere, presumably from the geocode request?
    Placemark * myPlacemark = [self getPlacemark];

    NSString * CurrentLocation = (NSString*)[self reverseGeocoder:myPlacemark];
}
```

Comment: @Himalay Let me know if I can can clarify my answer.